# Loading user control dynamically from server side

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control which inherits a class. (and I did some coding on `Oninit` function of this class). I am loading that user control dynamically from server side using the following approach:

```
Mycontrol dc = (Mycontrol)Page.LoadControl("/Controls/Mycontrol.ascx");
 MyPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(dc);
```

But the problem is that with this the `Oninit` function of the class inherited by the user control has not been executed. Can any one please tell me why this is happening and what is the solution for this.

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you have this code in your page ?I mean in which event ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for page life cycle events, the `OnInit` of child controls are called before the `OnInit` of the page.

That means that you have to add your dynamic controls in the `PreInit` event to have them in place before the event chain starts. In fact, the documentation for `PreInit` states that:

Use this event for the following:

- Check the IsPostBack property to determine whether this is the first
  time the page is being processed. The IsCallback and
  IsCrossPagePostBack properties have also been set at this time.
- Create or re-create dynamic controls.
- Set a master page dynamically.
- Set the Theme property dynamically.
- Read or set profile property
  values.